# Disadvantages of scoped-based memory management

Tags: c++, programming-languages, language-design, garbage-collection, raii

I really like scope-based memory management (SBMM), or *RAII*, as it is more commonly (confusingly?) referred to by the C++ community. As far as I know, except for C++ (and C), there's no other mainstream language in use today that makes SBMM/RAII their main memory management mechanism, and instead they prefer to use garbage collection (GC).

I find this rather confusing, since

1. SBMM makes programs more deterministic (you can tell exactly when an object is destroyed);
2. in languages that use GC you often have to do manual resource management (see closing files in Java, for example), which partly defeats the purpose of GC and is also error prone;
3. heap memory can also (very elegantly, imo) be scope-bound (see `std::shared_ptr` in C++).

Why is not SBMM more widely used? What are its disadvantages?

Comment: Some disadvantages (especially concerning speed) are discussed in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting#Advantages_and_disadvantages

Comment: Java's manual resource management problem is a side effect of not guaranteeing that an object's `finalize()` method will be called prior to garbage collection.  In effect, this creates the same class of problem that garbage collection is supposed to solve.

Comment: @Blrfl Nonsense. "Manual" resource management (for resources other than memory, obviously) would be preferable even if that "problem" did not exist, because GC can run a very long time after the resource becomes unused, or even not run at all. That's no problem for *memory*, and *memory* management is all that garbage collection is supposed to solve.

Comment: @delnan:  The cyclic reference problem in an environment that doesn't support pointers forces the adoption of the model that instances continue to exist after their reference counts reach zero.  Because there's no finalization at that point, it remains incumbent on the developer to know when non-memory instances are no longer needed and manually invoke a method to mop up, just like you would with memory of GC wasn't sweeping up behind you.  C++ gives you guaranteed destructors but not garbage collection, and those tradeoffs are what you evaluate when picking a language for a project.

Comment: @Blrfl: except that the cyclic reference problem lacks relevance to the kind of garbage collection that Java uses. There are other methods of automated memory management than reference counting.

Comment: btw. I  like to refer to it as SBRM since you can use the same mechanism to manage resources in general, not just memory.

Comment: related: [Did the developers of Java consciously abandon RAII?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/118295/31260)

Comment: @gnat Very interesting discussion. :)

Answer (score 28):

Let's start by postulating that memory is by far (dozens, hundreds or even thousands of time) more common than all other resources combined. Every single variable, object, object member needs some memory allocated to it and freed later on. For every file you open, you create dozens to millions of objects to store the data pulled out of the file. Every TCP stream goes together with an unbounded number of temporary byte strings created to be written to the stream. Are we on the same page here? Great.

For RAII to work (even if you have ready-made smart pointers for every use case under the sun), you need to get *ownership* right. You need to analyse who should own this or that object, who should not, and when ownership should be transferred from A to B. Sure, you could use shared ownership for *everything*, but then you'd be emulating a GC via smart pointers. At that point it becomes much easier *and* faster to build the GC into the language.

Garbage collection frees you from this concern for the by far most commonly used resource, memory. Sure, you still need to make the same decision for other resources, but those are far less common (see above), and complicated (e.g. shared) ownership is less common too. The mental burden is reduced significantly.

Now, you name some downsides to making *all* values garbage collected. However, integrating both memory-safe GC *and* value types with RAII into one language is extremely hard, so perhaps it's better to migitate these trade offs via other means?

The loss of determinism in turns out to be not that bad in practice, because it only affects deterministic *object lifetime*. As described in the next paragraph, most resources (aside from memory, which is plentiful and can be recycled rather lazily) are *not* bound to object lifetime in these languages. There are a few other uses cases, but they are rare in my experience.

Your second point, manual resource management, is nowadays addressed via a statement that does perform scope-based cleanup, but does not couple this clean up to the object life time (hence not interacting with the GC and memory safety). This is `using` in C#, `with` in Python, `try`-with-resources in recent Java versions.

Comment: This does not explain why nondeterministic models like GC should be superior to deterministic ones.

`using` statements are only possible locally. It's impossible to clean up resources held in member variables that way.

Comment: @Philipp Can you name a model that's fully deterministic yet doesn't have a concept of ownership? I'm not aware of any.

Comment: This is about shared ownership for everything vs. GC.

Comment: @Philipp Shared ownership for everything *is* a GC, just a very poor one. If you take "shared ownership" to imply ref counting, please say so, but keep the discussion about cycles in the comments on amon's answer. I'm also not sure whether ref counting is deterministic in the sense OP is interested in (objects are freed as early as possible, discounting cycles, but you often can't tell when that is by looking at the program). Moreover, ref counting for everything is slow, much slower than a modern tracing GC.

Comment: `using` is a joke compared to RAII, just so you know.

Comment: @DeadMG I would not phrase it so intentionally pejorative, but I am well aware of its limitations, yes.

Comment: to `using`, `with` and `try-with` (on C#, Python and Java, respectively) you can add `defer` in Go.

Comment: @Philipp please describe your metric for "superior". It is true that manual memory management is faster at run-time for dealing with memory management. However the cost of software cannot be judged purely on the CPU time spent on memory management alone.

Comment: @ArTs: I wouldn't even necessarily agree with this. RAII comes with the requirement that an object must be destroyed as it leaves scope. A loop, then, is required to do n object destructions. Under a modern generational GC, those destructions could be deferred until the end of the loop, or even later, and perform just one operation to destroy hundreds of iterations worth of memory. A GC *can* be very very fast in its good cases.

Comment: @Phoshi I chose my words carefully. For memory management RAII is very efficient. But as you noted, the full run-time does not necessarily require full memory management (deferred GC is still slow, but the point is GC can be deferred till the application terminates, in which case, you don't GC). My point is that focusing on just the memory management aspect would mean you don't see other possible optimizations.

Comment: Not really convinced. Most of the described uses of memory are essentially values, where you don't care about ownership. Here I have a string, I pass the thing, just as easy as an integer. The string doesn't have complex ownership internals (typically one private buffer, unshared) and in turn the string owner probably owns it outright (on stack, member, unique_ptr)

Comment: @delnan Ref counting using `shared_ptr`, as mentioned by the OP, should be as deterministic as other RAII-based mechanisms. About ref counting being slow, there is some research showing it can be made as fast as tracing GC: http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~steveb/downloads/pdf/rc-ismm-2012.pdf

Comment: @MSalters "Value" also implies ownership (namely, unique ownership). You still have to decide whether to use a value or something with different ownership.

Comment: @Philipp I use "ref counting" to mean "naive ref counting", since in practice almost all implementations use that. Smart refcounting *might* be an alternative to smart tracing GCs. Notes about that the paper though: (1) At least some of the techniques (didn't read the entire thing) use a backup precise GC (nominally for cycles only) and assign it crucial rules, e.g. `StuckRestore RC`. (2) These optimizations trade some of the collection promptness for performance, *especially* for young objects, making them less deterministic even without cycles.

Comment: As as example of a language that integrates memory-safe GC and value types with RAII, and that does it well, there's D: http://dlang.org/

Comment: Memory as you state is the most common resource, its however not the most scarce resource and that is where the problem lies with RAII-killing GC. Ideally we would want GC on ALL resources. Unfortunately that currently is not an option (yet). As a result we need to choose: Great resource management for memory and horrible resource management for anything else (GC) OR poor but unified resource management for everything (RAII). The mental burdon for GC is reduced for memory and shellow resources are easy enough to handle.The problem with the mental burden fir GC comes with 'deep' resources.

Answer (score 15):

RAII also follows from automatic reference-counting memory management, e.g. as used by Perl. While reference counting is easy to implement, deterministic, and quite performant, it cannot deal with circular references (they cause a leak) which is why it isn't commonly used.

Garbage-collected languages *can't* use RAII directly, but often do offer syntax with an equivalent effect. In Java, we have the try-with-ressource statement

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) { ... }
```

which automatically calls `.close()` on the resource on block exit. C# has the `IDisposable` interface, which allows `.Dispose()` to be called when leaving an `using (...) { ... }` statement. Python has the `with` statement:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    ...
```

which works in a similar fashion. In an interesting spin on this, Ruby's file open method gets a callback. After the callback has been executed, the file is closed.

```
File.open(name, mode) do |f|
    ...
end
```

I think Node.js uses the same strategy.

Comment: Using higher order functions for resource management dates back long before Ruby. In Lisps, it is quite common to have, say, `with-open-filehandle` functions which open the file, yield it to a function and upon return of the function close the file again.

Comment: The cyclic reference argument is quite common, but how important is it really? Cyclic references can be mitigated using weak pointers if ownership is clear.

Comment: @Philipp When you use ref counting, ownership usually *isn't* clear. Also, this answer talks about languages which use ref counting exclusively and automatically, so weak references either don't exist or are much harder to use than strong references.

Comment: @Philipp cyclic data structures are very rare, unless you're working with complicated graphs anyway. Weak pointers do not help in a general cyclic object graph, although they help in more common cases like parent pointers in a tree. A good workaround is to keep a context object that represents the reference to the whole graph, and manages destruction. Refcounting is not a dealbraker, but it requires that the programmer is very aware of its restrictions. I.e. it has a slightly higher cognitive cost than GC.

Comment: @amon "cyclic data structures are very rare, unless you're working with complicated graphs anyway." [Persistent data structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure) are one instance where you might have complicated graphs. On the other hand, if you're programming in C/C++ you probably don't care that much about referential transparency.

Comment: @Doval Nope. If the underlying data structure does not have cycles, a persistent version of that data structure won't have cycles either. The fact that one node may belong to any number of versions does not add complexity for refcounting memory management. I apologize if my use of “complicated graphs” in my above comment had been misunderstood for “anything more complex than a tree” when it meant “anything more complex than a DAG”.

Comment: An important reason why ref counting is rarely used is that it's often slower than GC, despite its simplicity.

Answer (score 13):

In my opinion the most convincing advantage of garbage collection is that it allows for **composability**. Correctness of memory management is a local property in garbage collected environment. You can look at each part in isolation and determine if it can leak memory. Combine any number of memory-correct parts and they stay correct.

When you rely on reference counting you lose that property. Whether your application can leak memory becomes a global property of the whole application with reference counting. Every new interaction between parts has the possibility to use the wrong ownership and break memory management.

It has a very visible effect on the design of programs in the different languages. Programs in GC-languages tend to be a bit more soups of objects with lots of interactions, while in GC-less languages one tends to prefer structured parts with strictly controlled and limited interactions between them.

Comment: Correctness is only composable if objects only hold references on their own behalf, and not on behalf of the targets of those references.  Once things like notifications enter into the mix (Bob holds a reference to Joe because Joe asked Bob to notify him when something happened and Bob promised to do so, but Bob otherwise doesn't care about Joe), GC correctness often requires scoped resource management [manually implemented in many cases, since GC systems lack the automation of C++].

Comment: @supercat: "GC correctness often requires scoped resource management". Eh? Scope only exists in the source code and GC only exists at run-time (and is, therefore, completely oblivious to the existence of scope).

Comment: @JonHarrop: I was using the term "scope" in the same sense as a C++ "scoped pointer" [the lifetime of the object should be that of the container holding it], since that's the usage implied by the original question. My point is that objects create potentially-long-lived references to themselves for purposes such as receiving events may not be composable in a purely-GC system. For correctness, certain references need to be strong and certain references need to be weak, and which references need to be which will depend upon how an object is used.  For example...

Comment: ...suppose objects Fred and Barney sign up for notification whenever anything in a certain directory is modified. Fred's handler does nothing but increment a counter whose value it can report on request, but for which it has no other use. Barney's handler will pop up a new window if a certain file is modified. For correctness, Fred should be subscribed with a weak event, but Barney's should be strong, but the timer object will have no way of knowing that.

Comment: @supercat: Right. I wouldn't say that happens "often". I've only come across it once in 30 years of programming.

Comment: @JonHarrop: Memory and resource leaks are not always fatal, and finalizers can often manage to make things work most of the time.  If clicking a button on a form will cause 100 bytes of memory to be allocated and uselessly retained until the form is closed, that would not be "correct", but may not cause major trouble unless the button gets clicked a million times.  I would posit that correctness frequently requires that objects be notified when their services are no longer needed, but is not always a requirement for programs to be usable.

Comment: @supercat: "I would posit that correctness frequently requires that objects be notified when their services are no longer needed". You're assuming the existence of objects. I have only ever encountered the problem you mentioned in the context of event-based programming. I rarely use events but, when I do, I use a constant number of listeners.

Answer (score 7):

Closures are an essential feature of pretty much all modern languages. They are very easy to implement with GC and very hard (though not impossible) to get right with RAII, since one of their main features is that they allow you to abstract over the lifetime of your variables!

C++ only got them 40 years after everybody else did, and it took a lot of hard work by a lot of smart people to get them right. In contrast, many scripting languages designed and implemented by people with zero knowledge in designing and implementing programming languages have them.

Comment: I don't think closures *in C++* are a good example. The lambdas in C++11 are just syntactic sugar for functor classes (which pre-date C++11 significantly), and are equally memory-unsafe: If you capture something by reference, and call the closure after that thing goes dead, you simply get UB, much like holding onto a reference longer than valid. That they appeared 40 years late is due to belated acknowledgement of FP, not due to figuring out how to make them safe. And while designing them was certainly a huge task, I doubt that most of the effort went into life time considerations.

Comment: I agree with delnan: C++ did not get closures right: you have to program them very carefully if you do not want to get a core dump when you invoke them.

Comment: @delnan: capture-by-reference lambda's very intentionally have that `[&]` syntax. Any C++ programmer already associates the `&` sign with references and knows about stale references.

Comment: @MSalters What's your point? I've drawn the reference connection myself. I did not say C++ lambdas are exceptionally unsafe, I said they are exactly as unsafe as references. I did not argue that C++ lambdas are bad, I argued against this answer's claim (that C++ got closures very late because they had to figure out how to do it right).

Answer (score 5):

> 1. SBMM makes programs more deterministic (you can tell exactly when an object is destroyed);

For most programmers the OS is non-deterministic, their memory allocator is non-deterministic and most of the programs they write are concurrent and, therefore, inherently non-deterministic. Adding the constraint that a destructor is called exactly at the end of scope rather than slightly before or slightly after is not a significant practical benefit for the vast majority of programmers.

> 2. in languages that use GC you often have to do manual resource management (see closing files in Java, for example), which partly defeats the purpose of GC and is also error prone;

See `using` in C# and `use` in F#.

> 3. heap memory can also (very elegantly, imo) be scope-bound (see std::shared_ptr in C++).

In other words, you could take the heap which is a general purpose solution and change it to only work in a specific case that is seriously limiting. That is true, of course, but useless.

> Why is not SBMM more widely used? What are its disadvantages?

SBMM limits what you can do:

1. SBMM creates the [upward funarg problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funarg_problem) with first-class lexical closures which is why closures are popular and easy to use in languages like C# but rare and tricky in C++. Note that there is a general trend towards the use of functional constructs in programming.
2. SBMM requires destructors and they impede tail calls by adding more work to do before a function can return. Tail calls are useful for extensible state machines and are provided by things like .NET.
3. Some data structures and algorithms are notoriously difficult to implement using SBMM. Basically anywhere that cycles are naturally occurring. Most notably graph algorithms. You effectively end up writing your own GC.
4. Concurrent programming is harder because control flow and, therefore, object lifetimes are inherently non-deterministic here. Practical solutions in message passing systems tend to be deep copying of messages and the use of excessively long lifetimes.
5. SBMM keeps objects alive until the end of their scope in the source code which is often longer than necessary and can be far longer than necessary. This increases the amount of floating garbage (unreachable objects waiting to be recycled). In contrast, tracing garbage collection tends to free objects soon after the last reference to them disappears which can be much sooner. See [Memory management myths: promptness](http://flyingfrogblog.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/memory-management-myths-promptness.html).

SBMM is so limiting that programmers need an escape route for situations where lifetimes can not be made to nest. In C++, `shared_ptr` offers an escape route but [it can be ~10x slower than tracing garbage collection](http://flyingfrogblog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/boosts-sharedptr-up-to-10-slower-than.html). So using SBMM instead of GC would put most people wrong footed most of the time. That is not to say, however, that it is useless. SBMM is still of value in the context of systems and embedded programming where resources are limited.

FWIW you might like to check out Forth and Ada, and read up on the work of Nicolas Wirth.

Comment: There are some things that you said that I find interesting and some things that I don't agree with (at least not entirely). I think we could have a pretty interesting discussion, but the comment section isn't very suitable for this, unfortunately.

Comment: If you say which bits I may be able to elaborate or cite articles.

Comment: How relevant is being 10x slower in a few rare use cases as opposed to being omnipresent in all use cases? C++ has unique_ptr and for most purposes its sufficient. Next to that, rather than attacking RAII trough C++ (a language that many love to hate for being an archaic language), if you are going to attack RAII trough attacking a language, try a younger sibling of the RAII family, Rust for example. Rust basically gets everything right that C++ got wrong while it gets most things right that C++ got right also. Further 'using' gets you a very limited set of use cases and ignores composition.

Comment: "How relevant is being 10x slower in a few rare use cases as opposed to being omnipresent in all use cases?". Firstly, that's a circular argument: `shared_ptr` is only rare in C++ because it is so slow. Secondly, that is an apples and oranges comparison (as the article I cited already showed) because `shared_ptr` is many times slower than a production GC. Thirdly, GCs are not omnipresent and are avoided in software like LMax and Rapid Addition's FIX engine.

Comment: "Further 'using' gets you a very limited set of use cases and ignores composition". If that were true then this "explosive" problem you keep mentioned should have bitten me at least once in the 30+ years I have been programming and, yet, I have never ever seen a single instance of it.

Comment: @Jon Harrop, If you havn't please enlighten me. What magic recipe have you used trough that 30+ years to mitigate the transitive effects of using deep resources? Without such a magic recipe after 30+ years I could only conclude that you must have misattributed being bitten by it to other causes.

Comment: @Jon Harrop, shared_ptr isn't rare because its slow, its rare for the reason that in a decently designed system the need for 'shared ownership' is rare.

Comment: @user1703394: "mitigate the transitive effects of using deep resources". You're repeating the same mistake. When you say "deep" what you really mean is "deep in an object hierarchy". The solution is to not use deep object hierarchies. This is exactly the kind of reason I stopped using object orientation extensively.

Comment: @Jon Harrop, That is 100% NOT what I really mean!!!! I mean deep as in "composition". Have a look at what the wikipedia article on resource management states about the transitive nature of "being a resource" than hopefully you will finally understand what RAII is all about. Lets say I have an 'actor' object that by composition holds a 'priority queue' object that by composition holds a number of 'fifo' object and these fifo object holds an open file handle.In that case the open file handle is a 'deep' resource.So once more: How did you mitigate the transitive effects of deep resources?

Comment: @user1703394: "Lets say I have an 'actor' **object** that by composition holds a 'priority queue' **object** that by composition holds a number of 'fifo' **object** and these fifo **object** holds an open file handle". There are two problems with your scenario. Firstly, you said you 100% do NOT mean deep object hierarchies and then you literally described a deep object hierarchy. Secondly, rather than presenting a problem you have presented a flawed design for a solution. What is the problem you are trying to solve? For example, I never store file handles in collections. Why would you?

Answer (score 4):

Looking at some popularity index like TIOBE (which is arguable, of course, but I guess for your kind of question its ok to use this) , you first see that ~50% of the top 20 are "scripting languages" or "SQL dialects", where the "ease of use" and means of abstraction have a much more importance than deterministic behaviour. From the remaining "compiled" languages, there are around 50% of the languages with SBMM and ~50% without. So when taking the scripting languages out of your calculation, I would say your assumption is just wrong, among compiled languages the ones with SBMM are as popular as the ones without.

Comment: How is "ease of use" different from determinism? Shouldn't a deterministic language be considered easier to use than a non-deterministic one?

Comment: @Philipp Only of the thing that's deterministic or not actually matters. Object life time doesn't matter on its own (though C++ and friends tie many things which matter to object life time, because they can). When an *unreachable* object is freed doesn't matter because, by definition, you aren't using it any more.

Comment: One more thing, various "scripting languages" like Perl and Python also use reference counting as primary means for memory management.

Comment: @Philipp At least in the Python world, this is considered an implementation detail of CPython, not a property of the language (and virtually every other implementation eschews refcounting). Moreover, I would argue that catch-all no-opt-out reference counting with backup cycle GC does not qualify as SBMM or RAII. In fact, you'd be hard pressed to find RAII proponents that are consider this style of memory management comparable to RAII (mostly because it isn't, cycles *anywhere* can prevent prompt deallocation anywhere else in the program).

Answer (score 3):

One major advantage of a GC system which nobody has mentioned yet is that *a reference in a GC system is guaranteed to retain its identity as long as it exists*.  If one calls `IDisposable.Dispose` (.NET) or `AutoCloseable.Close` (Java) on an object while copies of the reference exist, those copies will continue to refer to the same object.  The object won't be useful for anything anymore, but attempts to use it will have predictable behavior controlled by the object itself.  By contrast, in C++, if code calls `delete` on an object and later tries to use it, the entire state of the system becomes totally undefined.

Another important thing to note is that scope-based memory management works very well for objects with clearly-defined ownership.  It works much less well, and sometimes downright badly, with objects that have no defined ownership.  In general, mutable objects should have owners, while immutable objects don't need to, but there's a wrinkle: it's very common for code to use an instance of a mutable types to hold immutable data, by ensuring that no reference will be exposed to code that might mutate the instance.  In such a scenario, instances of the mutable class might be shared among multiple immutable objects, and thus have no clear ownership.

Comment: The property you refer to in the first half is memory safety. While a GC is a very easy way to achieve memory safety, a GC is not necessary: Look at Rust for a well-done example.

Comment: @delnan: When I view rust-lang.org, my browser can't seem to navigate usefully from there; where should I look for more information?  My impression is that memory safety without GC imposes certain restrictions on data structures which may not fit well with all the things an application might need to do, but I'd be happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: I don't know of a single (or even small set of) good references for this; my Rust knowledge has accumulated over a year or two of reading the mailing list (and all the stuff linked to in mails, including various tutorials, language design blog posts, github issues, ThisWeekInRust, and more). To briefly address your impression: Yes, each safe construct (necessarily) impose restrictions, but for virtually any memory safe piece of code, an appropriate safe construct exists or can be written. The by far most common ones already exist in language and stdlib, all others can be written in user code.

Comment: @delnan: Does Rust require interlocked updates to reference counters, or does it have some other means of dealing with immutable objects (or immutably-wrapped mutable objects) which have no definite ownership?  Does Rust have a concept of both "object-owning" and "non-owning" pointers?  I recall a paper on "Xonor" pointers which discussed the idea of objects having a single reference that "owns" them, and other references which do not; when the "owning" reference goes out of scope, all non-owning references would become references to dead objects, and would be identifiable as such...

Comment: ...for as long as they exist.  IMHO, that's the "right" general abstraction for mutable object instances (though not all instances of mutable types!); generally, as long as an object instance is mutable, it should have a single well-defined "owner".  Except in the scenario where the owner mutates the object on creation and then intends for it to be immutable after that, any use of a mutable object after the owner has abandoned it is apt to be a mistake.

Comment: Tasks (semantically, roughly equivalent to threads) do not share memory by default; `Rc<T>` is the standard task-local (and hence non-atomic) RC pointer type, then there's `Arc<T>` (immutable, atomic refcount) and `RWArc<T>` (mutable, read-write lock) for sharing data across tasks. There are owning references (e.g. `~T`) and non-owning references (e.g. `&T`, `&mut T`), the former can be turned into the latter and a combination of type system features makes sure borrowed references don't outlive the owner. (Other) smart pointers fit into this seamlessly (or at least will before 1.0).

Comment: @delnan: Will the compiler not allow references to task-local objects to be stored anywhere that may be visible on other threads?  Is there any way to have a common piece of code operate on both task-local and task-sharable objects?

Comment: I don't think Stack Exchange comments are the right medium to give a tour through a language. If you're still interested, you can go straight to the source (#rust IRC, rust-dev mailing list, etc.) and/or hit me up with a chat room (you should be able to create one).

Answer (score -2):

First off, its very important to realize that equating RAII to SBMM. or even to SBRM. One of the most essential (and least known or most under appreciated) qualities of RAII is the fact that it makes 'being a resource' a property that is NOT transitive to composition.

The following blog post discusses this important aspect of RAII and contrasts it to resource amangement in GCed languages that use non-deterministic GC.

http://minorfs.wordpress.com/2011/04/29/why-garbage-collection-is-anti-productive/

Its important to note that while RAII is mostly used in C++, Python (at last the non-VM based version) has destructors and deterministic GC that allows RAII to be used together with GC. Best of both worlds if it were.

Comment: +1 Interesting. I don't necessarily agree with his final conclusion that GC reduces productivity, but he does make a valid point that I haven't considered before (at least not as clearly as he put it in the article).

Comment: -1 That's one of the worst articles I've ever read.

Comment: The problem in languages isn't that they support GC, but that they abandon RAII.  There's no reason a language/framework shouldn't be able to support both.

Comment: @Jon Harrop, could you elaborate. Of the claims made in the article, is there even one of the first 3 claims that doesn't hold? I think you might disagree on the productivity claim, but the other 3 claims are absolutely valid. Most importantly the first one about the transitivity of being a resource.

Comment: @user1703394: Firstly, the entire article is based around a strawman "GCed language" when, in fact, it has nothing whatsoever to do with garbage collection. Secondly, he blames garbage collection when, in fact, the faults lie with object oriented programming. Finally, his argument is 10 years too late. The vast majority of programmers already modernised to garbage collected languages precisely because they offer much higher productivity.

Comment: His concrete examples (RAM, open file handles, locks, threads) are quite telling. I'm hard pressed to recall the last time I had to write code that dealt directly with any of those. With RAM, the GC automates everything. With file handles I write code like `File.ReadLines file |> Seq.length` where the abstractions handle closing for me. Locks and threads I've replaced with .NET `Task` and F# `MailboxProcessor`. This whole "We exploded the amount of manual resource management" is just complete nonsense.

Comment: @Jon, you are completely missing the real point of the article. Its not about "GCed language", its about "non deterministic destruction" braking RAII and about the concequences of braking RAII. The first 3 points are solid . The article shows that the basic advantage of RAII is that it removes the transitivity property of 'being a resource'. The article shows that by applying 'non deterministic GC' you will implicitly make 'being a resource' transitive to composition. Claims on productivity could be wrong,transitivity of 'being a resource' is the important part here regardless of productivity.

Comment: "The article shows that by applying 'non deterministic GC' you will implicitly make 'being a resource' transitive to composition". GC has nothing to do with that. You can require every class to implement a destructor that is called at the end of scope whether you have a GC or not.

Comment: @Jon Harrop, If you can than you must have "deterministic" GC, "non-deterministic" GC implies that 'end of scope' is just a 'not before' marker for destuctor invocation and basically there is no 'not after' defined. The destructor in non-deterministic GC might be called immediately or two months from end of scope.

Comment: @user1703394: "The destructor in non-deterministic GC might be called immediately or two months from end of scope". The destructor is still called at the end of scope, just like C++. Look at F#, for example, where the `IDisposable` interface is called at the end of scope of any `use` binding.

Comment: @Jon Harrop, The "use" and the "IDisposable" are artifacts of 'being a resource' that is the whole point of the article. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_management_(computing)#Resource_management_without_RAII

Comment: @user1703394 **"non-deterministic" GC implies that 'end of scope' is just a 'not before' marker** That is a common misconception. Tracing GCs can and do collect before the end of scope.

Comment: @user1703394 **The destructor in non-deterministic GC might be called immediately or two months from end of scope.** You are confusing finalizers and destructors. Finalizers are related to GC and have nothing to do with this. Destructors have nothing to do with GC and everything to do with this. You can have both with a tracing GC.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_management_(computing)#The_dispose_pattern

Comment: Let me repeat the concrete counter example I already gave: the `System.IO.File.ReadLines` function returns an `IEnumerable` that reads the lines of a file on-demand (i.e. with an open file handle) yet it is not an `IDisposable`. So "being a resource" is clearly not transitive to composition on .NET despite the absence of RAII, disproving your belief (which you appear to have posted on Wikipedia).

Comment: You seem to be confused about what composition refers to. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition